# ARQ Protocols and sequence numbers

Tags: efficiency, computer-networks

What will happen if sequence number is not used in an ARQ protocol (e.g, Go-back-N, selective repeat)?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?  What have you done to try to figure this out on your own?  Have you done some reading in a standard textbook?  Can you enumerate the properties needed from an ARQ protocol?  Have you tried to work out whether those protocols would have each of those properties, without a sequence number?

Answer (score 1):

You're basically asking "what happens when a critical part of the ARQ protocol is missing?"  To name a few consequences: it wouldn't know when to stop ACK'ing incoming packets, or know if they are coming in the right order, or know if all of them got there.